# Covariant derivative versus exterior derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, connections

$\def\alt{\textrm{Alt}} \def\d{\mathrm{d}}  \def\sgn{\mathrm{sgn}\,}$Let $\nabla$ be a symmetric linear connection in $M$, and $\omega$ be a $k$-form in $M$. I'm trying to find a relation between $\d\omega$ and $\nabla \omega$. I follow Spivak's notation in Calculus on Manifolds and write $$\alt(\nabla \omega)(X_1,\cdots,X_{k+1}) = \frac{1}{(k+1)!}\sum_{\sigma \in S_{k+1}} (\sgn \sigma)\nabla\omega(X_{\sigma(1)},\cdots,X_{\sigma(k+1)}).$$I also assume the formula $$\d\omega(X_1,\cdots,X_{k+1})=\sum_{i=1}^k(-1)^{i+1}X_i(\omega(X_1,\cdots,\widehat{X_i},\cdots,X_{k+1})) + \sum_{i<j}(-1)^{i+j}\omega([X_i,X_j],X_1,\cdots,\widehat{X_i},\cdots,\widehat{X_j},\cdots,X_{k+1}).$$I'd expect something like $\alt(\nabla\omega) = \d \omega$, apart from a multiplicative constant, maybe. I'm stuck. For $k=1$ I got $$\alt(\nabla \omega) = -\frac{1}{2}\d \omega.$$The $1/2$ I can accept, but the minus sign puts me off. I tried brute forcing my way through $k=2$ but I guess I just suck at doing computations like this.

The best I can come up with is

$$\begin{align} (k+1)!\alt(&\nabla\omega)(X_1,\cdots,X_{k+1}) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_{k+1}} (\sgn\sigma) \nabla\omega(X_{\sigma(1)},\cdots,X_{\sigma(k+1)}) \\ &= \sum_{\sigma \in S_{k+1}} (\sgn\sigma) \nabla_{X_{\sigma(k+1)}}\omega(X_{\sigma(1)},\cdots,X_{\sigma(k)}) \\ &= \sum_{\sigma \in S_{k+1}}(\sgn\sigma)\left(X_{\sigma(k+1)}(\omega(X_{\sigma(1)},\cdots,X_{\sigma(k)})) - \sum_{i=1}^n\omega(X_{\sigma(1)},\cdots, \nabla_{X_{\sigma(k+1)}}X_{\sigma(i)},\cdots,X_{\sigma(k)})\right)\\ &= \sum_{\sigma \in S_{k+1}}(\sgn\sigma)X_{\sigma(k+1)}(\omega(X_{\sigma(1)},\cdots,X_{\sigma(k)})) - \sum_{\sigma \in S_{k+1}}\sum_{i=1}^n(\sgn \sigma)\omega(X_{\sigma(1)},\cdots, \nabla_{X_{\sigma(k+1)}}X_{\sigma(i)},\cdots,X_{\sigma(k)}) \\ &\stackrel{\color{red}{(\ast)}}{=} \sum_{\sigma \in S_{k+1}}X_{\sigma(k+1)}(\omega(X_1,\cdots,X_k)) - \sum_{\sigma \in S_{k+1}}\sum_{i=1}^n(\sgn \sigma)\omega(X_{\sigma(1)},\cdots, \nabla_{X_{\sigma(k+1)}}X_{\sigma(i)},\cdots,X_{\sigma(k)})\end{align}$$

and I'm stuck. I'm not sure of the $\color{red}{(\ast)}$ step either. I know that we must use that $\nabla$ is symmetric to get rid of all these $\nabla$ but I don't know how to do this. What is the smart way to do this?

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358127/covariant-derivative-vs-exterior-derivative) is the most similar thing to what I'm trying to do that I found, but I don't find it easy to see such relation, as it is said there. Also, I'd like to avoid coordinate computations if possible.

---

I'll ignore the $\color{red}{(\ast)}$ step since I think it is wrong. I don't know how to write it neatly, but doing it for $k=1$ and $k=2$ suggests $$\sum_{\sigma \in S_{k+1}}(\sgn \sigma)X_{\sigma(k+1)}(\omega(X_{\sigma(1)},\cdots,X_{\sigma(k)})) = (-1)^kk!\sum_{i=1}^k(-1)^iX_i(\omega(X_1,\cdots,\widehat{X_i},\cdots,X_{k+1})).$$Also, it seems that $$\sum_{\sigma \in S_{k+1}}\sum_{i=1}^k(\sgn \sigma)\omega(X_{\sigma(1)},\cdots, \nabla_{X_{\sigma(k+1)}}X_{\sigma(i)},\cdots,X_{\sigma(k)})=(-1)^{k+1}k!\sum_{i<j}(-1)^{i+j}\omega([X_i,X_j],X_1,\cdots,\widehat{X_i},\cdots,\widehat{X_j},\cdots,X_{k+1})$$

So: $$(k+1)! {\rm Alt}(\nabla \omega) = (-1)^kk!{\rm d}\omega \implies (-1)^k(k+1)\alt(\nabla \omega) = {\rm d}\omega.$$

Comment: Cartan uses Covariant derivatives of an arbitrary frame to generalize Frenet's formulas. The generalization heavily uses forms so maybe there is some connection there for you. This may be irrelevant since it one uses 1-forms.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Three comments:

1. There are two different conventions in common use for the wedge product. The one Spivak uses and I use (which I call the *determinant convention*) is
   $$
   \alpha \wedge \beta = \frac{(k+l)!}{k!l!} \operatorname{Alt}(\alpha\otimes\beta),
   $$
   when $\alpha$ is a $k$-form and $\beta$ is an $l$-form. The one Kobayashi & Nomizu use (the *Alt convention*) is
   $$
   \alpha \wedge \beta = \operatorname{Alt}(\alpha\otimes\beta).
   $$
   The formula you wrote down for $d\omega$ is correct if you're using the determinant convention. But the formula $d\omega = \operatorname{Alt}(\nabla\omega)$ would only be correct using the Alt convention. With the determinant convention, the formula should be $d\omega = \pm (k+1)\operatorname{Alt}(\nabla\omega)$ when $\omega$ is a $k$-form.
2. The plus or minus sign depends on how you define the $(k+1)$-tensor $\nabla \omega$. Some authors define it to be 
   $$\nabla\omega(\dots,Y) = \nabla_Y\omega(\dots),$$
   while others define it to be 
   $$\nabla\omega(Y,\dots) = \nabla_Y\omega(\dots).$$
   Your computation shows that you're using the first convention, in which case the correct formula is $d\omega = (-1)^k (k+1)\operatorname{Alt} (\nabla\omega)$.
3. To derive your formula $\color{red}{(\ast)}$ (or rather the version with the correct constant multiple) by brute force, you can note that each of the terms of the form $\nabla_{X_i} X_j$ can be matched up with a term $\nabla_{X_j} X_i$ with the opposite sign, and because the connection is symmetric, these combine to give $[X_i,X_j]$, which then matches one of the terms in the formula for $d\omega$. But a much easier approach is to note that both $d\omega$ and $\operatorname{Alt}(\nabla\omega)$ are well-defined tensor fields, and thus their values at a point $p$ can be compared in terms of any convenient local frame. If you let the $X_i$'s be coordinate vector fields in Riemannian normal coordinates centered at $p$, then many terms go away.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. I didn't knew about the other convention for the definition of $\nabla \omega$. Just one thing, though.. are you sure about ${\rm d}\omega = (-1)^k(k+1){\rm Alt}(\nabla \omega)$? I didn't put the factor in my formula for ${\rm d}\omega$. I did the computation for $k=2$ and I got $3{\rm Alt}(\nabla \omega) = 2{\rm d}\omega$. The sign is ok. With this setting, shouldn't it be $${\rm d}\omega = (-1)^k \frac{k+1}{k}{\rm Alt}(\nabla \omega)?$$Thanks for the patience.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, I forgot a $!$. Everything fits. :-)

Answer (score 5):

This is only a partial answer.

This result is proved in Kobayashi-Nomizu, *Foundations of differential geometry*, vol. 1: it's Corollary 8.6 p.149 ($\operatorname{Alt}(\nabla w) = dw$ holds for any torsion-free connection $\nabla$). But it does not look like their proof is what you are looking for.

I understand the calculation that you are trying to do and I'm not sure how to fix it, but here is an observation that may help: if $\omega$ is a $k$-form, in other words an element of $\Gamma(\Lambda^k T^*M)$, then $\nabla \omega$ is an element of $\Gamma(T^*M \otimes \Lambda^k T^*M)$, so I think that $\operatorname{Alt}(\nabla w)$ is simply given by $\operatorname{Alt}(\nabla w) = \sigma(\nabla w)$, where $\sigma : \Gamma(T^*M \otimes \Lambda^k T^*M) \to \Gamma(\Lambda^{k+1} T^*M)$ is the linear map given by $\sigma(\alpha \otimes \eta) = \alpha \wedge \eta$. In [this paper](http://users.math.msu.edu/users/parker/ga/geometryprimer.pdf), they proceed to show the result, but they use local coordinates. It's probably possible to do a coordinate-free proof like you want but I haven't tried long enough.

Comment: This is a good start, thanks! I'll look up these references.